# Is LineString in OpenLayers 6 drawn geodesic?

Tags: openlayers-6

I am drawing some lines (LineString) which are 400km long. The middle point doesn't seem to be exactly where it should be, but it's close (say 3km out). It looks like the LineString is not being drawn geodesic. Can't find anything in the documentation to say either way. So the question is: is LineString drawn geodesic, and if not, how do I make it do so?

Comment: No, if you want geodesic lines you would need a utility such as arcGenerator as used in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/flight-animation.html  If drawing you could style the drawn line using geometry calculated with arcGenerator https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285745/draw-great-circle-line-on-the-map-directly-in-openlayers-5

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the related question:[Draw great circle line on the map directly in OpenLayers 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285745/draw-great-circle-line-on-the-map-directly-in-openlayers-5)
referenced in @Mike's comment, you can style the drawn line so it is geodesic using a geometry calculated with arcGenerator (from [arc.js](https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/arc.js/v0.1.0/arc.js)):

```
new ol.style.Style({
  geometry: function(feature) {
    var projection = map.getView().getProjection();
    var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().clone().transform(projection, 'EPSG:4326').getCoordinates();
    var from = coordinates[0];
    var to = coordinates[1];
    var arcGenerator = new arc.GreatCircle({
      x: from[0],
      y: from[1]
    }, {
      x: to[0],
      y: to[1]
    });
    var arcLine = arcGenerator.Arc(100, {
      offset: 10
    });
    var coords = [];
    arcLine.geometries.forEach(function(geom) {
      coords.push(geom.coords);
    });
    var line = new ol.geom.MultiLineString(coords);
    line.transform('EPSG:4326', projection);
    return line;
  },
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    width: 2,
    color: 'blue'
  })
});
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_6.4.3_geodesicLineString.html)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
// from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285745/draw-great-circle-line-on-the-map-directly-in-openlayers-5

var styleSimple2ptLine = new ol.style.Style({
  geometry: function(feature) {
    var projection = map.getView().getProjection();
    var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().clone().transform(projection, 'EPSG:4326').getCoordinates();
    var from = coordinates[0];
    var to = coordinates[1];
    var arcGenerator = new arc.GreatCircle({
      x: from[0],
      y: from[1]
    }, {
      x: to[0],
      y: to[1]
    });
    var arcLine = arcGenerator.Arc(100, {
      offset: 10
    });
    var coords = [];
    arcLine.geometries.forEach(function(geom) {
      coords.push(geom.coords);
    });
    var line = new ol.geom.MultiLineString(coords);
    line.transform('EPSG:4326', projection);
    return line;
  },
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    width: 2,
    color: 'blue'
  })
});

var coordsSimple = [ol.proj.fromLonLat([121.74940748038463, 31.3038498266498]),
  ol.proj.fromLonLat([139.793414, 35.599839])
];
const lineStr = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordsSimple)
});
const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [lineStr]
});
const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: styleSimple2ptLine
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, vectorLayer],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});

map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), {
  padding: [50, 50, 50, 50]
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/arc.js/v0.1.0/arc.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```